# How to distinguish between instances of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have multiple instances of VS Code open, I would like to quickly determine which instance I am working with.  I tried changing the theme of an instance but the change impacts all instances.

Am I overlooking an option?  Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't the documents open in the editor be a great discriminating factor? / How do you tell the difference in your other favorite text editor?

Comment: @Jeroen This was of interest to me at the time because I was migrating code from one project to another and wanted it to be very obvious which was the source project and which was the destination project.  This is not an every day need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An old question, but for anyone looking here still you probably want to try [Peacock](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock). From the description:

> Subtly change the color of your Visual Studio Code workspace. Ideal when you have multiple VS Code instances, use VS Live Share, or use VS Code's Remote features, and you want to quickly identify your editor.

Given how lightweight VS Code is, I find myself with multiple instances open all the time without thinking as I switch between projects, assigning each one a new colour using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command pallette, and choosing '**Peacock: Surprise me with a random colour**'.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution like this forever. Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would check for the window title, it has the name of the folder you opened it with as suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this was not obvious enough for my need at the time.  See my comment to Jeroen in the question.